# Create new folder in Program Files folder

Tags: vba, ms-access

I made an Access DB and I need to create a folder to it in path

```
C:\Program Files
```

I tried

```
MkDir Path:="C:\Program Files\My Pro"
```

to create my folder "My Pro"

I receive [Run-time error '75': Path/File access](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rxx5f.png)

I tried this Code

```
Dim objShell
Dim objFolder

Set objShell = CreateObject("shell.application")
Set objFolder = objShell.NameSpace("C:\Program Files")

If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
    objFolder.NewFolder ("My Pro")
End If

Set objFolder = Nothing
Set objShell = Nothing
```

and this code

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder("C:\Program Files\My Pro")
```

I receive [Run-time error '70': Permission denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzGM2.png)

How can I create a new folder in the Program Files folder with Access VBA?

Comment: VB.NET is not VBA. Would be worth using the correct tags.

Answer (score 0):

To create folder in Program Files you **need administrator rights**. Build your app to EXE, right click on it and click **Run as Administrator**.

This should fix the problem.

EDIT: This might help you: https://www.itsupportguides.com/windows-7/windows-7-run-vbs-script-as-elevated-user-uac/

Comment: thanks my friends but i wanna ask you about premission of ms access db how i do that with code ... i mean how i get administrator rights to my access db by vb befor i creat new folder

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize that :-)

Comment: So try run MS Access as Administrator

Comment: if i run ms access as Administrator  all code above is run perfect and i can create folder easy so my question is how i get administrator rights by vb  before run my code in ms access